# Makefile : What does @VAR@ do?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autoconf

I'm trying to build mod_wsgi from sources.
But when I'm trying to use "make", I get the following issue :

```
/bin/sh: APXS@: command not found
Makefile.in:31: recipe for target 'src/server/mod_wsgi.la' failed
make: *** [src/server/mod_wsgi.la] Error 127
```

I checked the *Makefile.in* file and I line 31 is this one :

```
    $(APXS) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCFILES) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

And at the line 15 :

```
APXS = @APXS@
```

I checked and apxs is installed.
What is `@APXS@` supposed to do? Giving the path to apxs? (like `which apxs`?) Use an environment variable?
Why doesn't it work here? I'm building a docker container, could it be the problem?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@VAR@` notation is an **autoconf** idiosyncrasy, together with the `.in` suffix in your file `Makefile.in`, it leads me to think that you did not `./configure` your package.

### What does it mean to configure my package?

The **autoconf** software is a tool to write `./configure` scripts, meant to detect the characteristics of the system they are running on: What is the path where *this* program is stored? Where are *these* C headers? These are questions typically answered by the `./configure` script.  When it has gathered its answers, it exports the answers by processing a list of files – usually ending with `.in` like your `Makefile.in` – and replaces the `@VAR@` placeholders by the values it guessed.

### How do I configure my package?

I do not know the details of your software package, but given the information you provided, you should try to run the `./configure` script. Use `./configure --help` to review its options.  If such a script is not available, try to generate it by using the `autoconf` command in the toplevel directory of your package.

Comment: It makes sense.
I already runned the **configure** script before but without understanding its purpose. It builded the **Makefile** in the wrong directory, I just found this out now. But I didn't understand why **make** didn't find the Makefile, so I manually passed **Makefile.in** to it. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: I was trying to build it from the wrong directory, I just added a **cd /the/right/dir** to my Dockerfile and it worked fine. :)

Comment: If you are specifically wanting to use mod_wsgi in Docker, then use my Docker image. https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/grahamdumpleton/mod-wsgi-docker/